# Session is not declared Error

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I HAVE THE FOLLOWING CODE:

```
Try
            Select Case process.datain
                Case "home"
                    MOTable = selectMO(process.mo, process.mt)
                    If MOTable.Rows.Count() = 0 Then
                        If insertMO(process.mo, process.mt) Then
                            writeMsg("1 MO inserted/updated at ")
                            session("msg") = msgTable.Rows(7)(1).ToString()
                            MsgBox(session("msg"))
                        Else
                            writeMsg("1 MO could not be inserted at ")
                        End If
 Catch ex As Exception
            logFile("executeTimer ----" & ex.Message)
        Finally
            updateProcessed(process.id,session("msg"))
        End Try
```

I'M FACING AN ERROR TELLING ME THAT SESSION IS NOT DECLARED... BUT I NEED TO USE A SESSION TO GET THE VALUE OF THE ROW BECAUSE I NEED TO PASS IT LATER ON AT THE END OF THE CODE AS PARAMETER FOR A STORED PROCEDURE

i even tried using :

```
session.add("msg", msgTable.Rows(7)(1).ToString())
```

but i'm facing the same error

CAN YOU HELP ME PLEASEEEEE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your project reference System.Web ? (Imports)
(If it does import it , add it manually by right clicking on your solution , add Reference, System.Web)

Comment: Manually as well ? Right click on your project at solution explorer --> Add reference --> System.Web

Comment: i tried the manual add but i'm still facing the same error ... :(

Comment: Try System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“msg”) = msgTable.Rows(7)(1).ToString()

Comment: Adding the reference should have fixed it, are you sure you manually added it like I said ? Once you add the System.Web reference, "HTTPContext" should be highlighted in blue in your code - meaning you can use it.

Comment: when adding manually i have only system.web.services and system.web.ApplicationServices i do not have system.web only

Comment: Right click on your solution, go to properties, open the Application tab on the left, what is your target framework ?

Comment: okey i did now and i used System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("msg") = msgTable.Rows(7)(1).ToString() but now i'm having another error : object reference not set to an instance of an object ! now what ?? :(

Comment: Are you using an aspx page ?(ASP project ) Because Sessions are a property to ASP pages. Or are you just writing this code in your class?

Comment: And just use a normal variable, you don't need sessions .